# How can I get the default content of WordPress post?

Tags: filters, the-content

Is there a way where I can get the default output of the_content in WordPress post?
Some of the plugin is using add_filter to the content to add their desired result like related post plugins where they add the result at the end of the content of a post.
What I want to happen is to get the default formatting functions of WordPress without any additional filters from other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access the post_content property in the loop from the $post object

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
  echo $post->post_content
endwhile; endif;
```

Mention that the post_content is coming straight from the database.
All 'the_content' filters will not be applied.

For more properties see the [post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) codex

Comment: Thanks for responding @s_ferdie but what I want to get is the default post_content with just the filters coming wordpress core.